# Index value not getting correctly updated

Tags: javascript

I have a popup and i select the value and it gets updated correctly in my field.

```
var boolArray = ['Yes', 'No'];    
textField.value = boolArray[e.index] == undefined ? textField.value : boolArray[e.index];
```

But when i send the `somevalue` to my service, it does update incorrectly. for instance if i select Yes, it send NO and Vice Versa.

```
var somevalue = e.index === undefined ? '' : e.index;
```

Comment: Did you forget `boolArray` in the second snippet somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the first line to `var boolArray = ['No', 'Yes'];`

I believe you want to show this way:

- if e.index=undefined, textField.value=textField.value and
  somevalue=""
- if e.index=0, textField.value="No" and somevalue=0
- if e.index=1, textField.value="Yes" and somevalue=1

In short, 1 means yes, 0 means no